# How to get OracleConnection for storing JGeometry to Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, exception

I am trying store JGeometry to Oracle database with the following code:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

...

```
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    session.doWork(new Work() {

        @Override
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE SAMPLE_AREA SET GEOMETRY=? WHERE ID = " + sampleAreaId + " AND SAMPLE_ID = " + sampleId);
            System.out.println(connection); // prints: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler@321ca777[valid=true]
            System.out.println(connection.getClass().getName()); // prints: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125 
            STRUCT obj = JGeometry.store(jGeometry, connection);
            ps.setObject(1, obj);
            ps.execute();

        }
    });
```

I am getting java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection when calling JGeometry.store.

How can I get OracleConnection?

I am using "hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"

Comment: Or is there some other way to store geometry in to ORACLE database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Instead of using Connection as parameter to JGeometry.store one needs to use OracleConnection. That can be unwrapped from Connection. I think I tried this before, but most likely I had wrong import, correct is oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.

```
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
...
OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap( OracleConnection.class );
STRUCT obj = JGeometry.store(jGeometry, oracleConnection);
```